# Access violation exception while using std::string, other types are ok

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, unique-ptr

so I'm writing my own vector class and it goes pretty well but I ran into problems with string type. Whole class is template and does pretty much same stuff as std::vector does, it works on int, double, float, char, but when it comes to std::string... it doesnt. Even the simpliest method crashes and throws read access violtion. Here is a bit of code

Part of header file

```
template <class T>
class MyVector{
    std::unique_ptr<T[]> m_array;
    int m_size; 
    int m_capacity; 
};
```

Constructor

```
template <class T>
MyVector<T>::MyVector() : m_capacity(2), m_size(0) {
    m_array = std::make_unique<T[]>(m_capacity);
}
```

ExtendArray method

```
template <class T>
void MyVector<T>::extendArray() {
    m_capacity *= 2;
    std::unique_ptr<T[]> temp_array = std::move(m_array);
    m_array = std::make_unique<T[]>(m_capacity);
    std::copy(temp_array.get(), temp_array.get() + m_capacity / 2, m_array.get());
}
```

PushBack method

```
template <class T>
void MyVector<T>::pushBack(const T& p_element) {
    if (m_size == m_capacity) extendArray();
    m_array[m_size] = p_element;
    m_size++;
}
```

InsertAt method, inserts element at given index and then moves rest of array

```
template <class T>
void MyVector<T>::insertAt(int index, const T& p_element) { 
        if (m_size >= m_capacity - 1) extendArray();            
        if (m_array[index] == T{}) {
            m_array[index] = p_element;
            m_size++;
        }
        else {
            std::copy(m_array.get() + index, m_array.get() + m_capacity, m_array.get() + index + 1);
            m_array[index] = p_element;
            m_size++;
        }
}
```

**Problem 1**
PushBack method works fine, I keep adding elements of all types (including string), and its ok. Problem happens when then I try to use insertAt method

```
int main() {    
    MyVector<std::string> vec;
    vec.pushBack("Ok here");
    vec.pushBack("Extending array now");
    vec.pushBack("Still no errors");
    vec.insertAt(1, "Here comes the exception");
    std::cin.get();
}
```

I get

> Exception thrown at 0x589750B9 (vcruntime140d.dll) in MySTL.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xB9B431B6.

If I do same thing on char, int, float, double, everything works fine.

**Problem 2**
I started this project on Ubuntu, compiled it with G++ and I had no problems with templates, now Im working on Windows, using VS 2017 Community and I need to add

```
template class MyVector<std::string>;
template class MyVector<int>;
template class MyVector<float>;
```

etc in my .cpp in order to compile this, if type isnt defined like that, it just dont compile... any other, better solution?

**Problem 3**
On G++ I had no problems with adding other classes to my vector, now I cant do that. Even If i declare simple class in .cpp like that for example

```
class Test {
    int m_x;
public:
    Test() {}
    Test(int p_x) : m_x(p_x) {}
    int getX() { return m_x; };
};

template class MyVector <Test>;
```

it doesnt work, I get a lot of compiler errors like this

> error C2676: binary '==': 'Test' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

pointing to

```
if (m_array[index] == T{})
```

on G++ both NULL or T{} worked, now neither of they works.

Comment: So what's the size of an array if you start it at size 0 and then insert at position 10000? And what the heck does this `m_array[index] == T{}` actually do?

Comment: std::vector doesnt allow that, for brief moment I was checking for that (index > capacity) and function was calling extendArray before, it would lead to another errors I wanted to avoid for now. == T{} works pretty much the same as == NULL, found that somewhere and it worked for me.

Comment: Long story short, that thing you have seen somewhere is totally broken (99% of C++ things you can see somewhere are totally broken), and so is your design because of it. Throw it away and start again. A vector shouldn't ever compare values of its elements. The only thing it is allowed to do is to copy them, any violation of this is a bug and I have test cases to prove it (but try to find the problem yourself, what happens if your vector contains many zero elements?)

Comment: As for the crash, the behaviour is undefined if the input and the output range in `std::copy` arguments overlap. This is exactly what happens with your `insertAt`.

Comment: So I shouldnt ever use `==` inside my vector class? Too bad I used this `T{]` few times, how do I check if element is empty or how do I assign element as empty? And tbh, I dont really get what you mean that in `std::copy` my arguments overlap?

Comment: Per the `cppreference.com` documentation for [`std::copy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) and [`std::copy_backward()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_backward): "*When copying overlapping ranges, `std::copy` is appropriate when copying to the left (beginning of the destination range is outside the source range) while `std::copy_backward` is appropriate when copying to the right (end of the destination range is outside the source range).*"

Comment: @Emdzej93: there is no reason to perform `==` in `insertAt()`. You NEVER need to check element values, especially considering that not all types even have a concept of an "empty" value. If an element falls within the `[0, size)` range, it is a valid element regardless of its value. `insertAt()` needs to just move over the elements to the right of the specified index and then insert the new value at the specified index. No comparisons needed

Comment: Well yeah forget about `==`, but what about `=`? I was thinking about `removeAt` which code looks like this `std::copy(m_array.get() + index + 1, m_array.get() + m_capacity, m_array.get() + index);
  m_array[m_size] = T{};` I need to clear last element somehow after copying rest of array

Comment: About `insertAt`, its `std::copy_backward` should look like that? `std::copy_backward(m_array.get() + index, m_array.get() + m_capacity, m_array.get() + m_capacity);` Im getting [begin, end] of range into end of destination? Cus its not working for me :/

Comment: That's absolutely right, don't use `==` and don't use `T{}`. **There's so such thing as empty element**. All elements at indices from `0` to `size-1` inclusively are occupied, you don't need to compare them with anything to know that. Ideally you should allow for element types that don't even have default constructors, but this may prove rather tricky for a beginner/intermediate C++ programmer.

Comment: Yes, std::copy_backward is good in this case. Remember, you are only interested in indices, not in values. Always copy the range.

Comment: So how do I remove element? I call `removeAt(x)`, so I just copy everything from x+1 to m_capacity into x, that way I get rid of that what was under x. But then Ill have duplicate of last element at the end, how do I reset this last element? And what's more, why this thing isnt working for me? `std::copy_backward(m_array.get() + index, m_array.get() + m_size, m_array.get() + m_size);
  m_array[index] = p_element;` I pushBack few items in main.cpp, then I call `insertAt` and yeah, it inserts element at given index but doesnt copy and doesnt move my array, just replaces what was under index

Comment: "I need to clear last element" no, you don't. Just decrement the size. Whatever is beyond `[0, size)` should not be accessed anyway, so nobody cares if you have some old value in there. `m_array[m_size] = T{};` won't do anything useful (but won't harm either).

Comment: "why this thing isnt working for me" You need `std::copy_backward(m_array.get() + index, m_array.get() + m_size, m_array.get() + m_size+1)`.